# Binary instance for Static Pointers

Tags: haskell, cloud-haskell

I have the following data type

```
data Foo a b = A (StaticPtr (a -> b)) deriving (Generic, Typeable)
```

I want to generate the Binary instance for this type so I can use this function on a remote node.

However, using automatic Binary instantiation doesn't work here:

```
instance (Binary a, Binary b) => Binary (Foo a b)
```

This results in

```
• Could not deduce (Binary (StaticPtr (a -> b)))
    arising from a use of ‘binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.$dmput’
  from the context: (Binary a, Binary b)
    bound by the instance declaration
    at /Users/abhiroop/Haskell/snape/app/Spec.hs:23:10-49
• In the expression:
    binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.$dmput @Foo a b
  In an equation for ‘binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.put’:
      binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.put
        = binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.$dmput @Foo a b
  In the instance declaration for ‘Binary (Foo a b)’


• Could not deduce (Binary (StaticPtr (a -> b)))
    arising from a use of ‘binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.$dmget’
  from the context: (Binary a, Binary b)
    bound by the instance declaration
    at /Users/abhiroop/Haskell/snape/app/Spec.hs:23:10-49
• In the expression:
    binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.$dmget @Foo a b
  In an equation for ‘binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.get’:
      binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.get
        = binary-0.8.5.1:Data.Binary.Class.$dmget @Foo a b
  In the instance declaration for ‘Binary (Foo a b)’
```

How do I auto generate the `Binary` instance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Li-yao Xia's answer is correct. But I had to change my data types, in general, to pass them remotely. I am writing my changes here so it might be useful if someone wants to send a function remotely, there isn't many resources on this online.

So instead of having

```
data Foo a b = A (StaticPtr (a -> b))
```

I have changed my data types to look like this:

```
data Foo a b = A (a -> b)
```

or to simplify

```
data Foo f = A f
```

Here `f` is the function I want to send remotely.

So taking a simple example of a function like `(+ 1)` and imagine I want to map this over a list `[1,2,3]` which is present remotely. My code becomes like this:

```
main :: IO [Int]
main = do
let list = [1,2,3]
    a = static (A (+ 1)) :: StaticPtr (Foo (Int -> Int))
    t = staticKey a
    -- assuming you sent t to the remote node
    -- code on the remote node
    x <- unsafeLookupStaticPtr t
    case x of
      Just sptr -> case deRefStaticPtr sptr of
                         A f -> return $ map f list
                         _   -> error "Task undefined"
      Nothing -> error "Wrong function serialized"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize a `StaticPtr` as a `Fingerprint` via [`staticKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/GHC-StaticPtr.html#v:staticKey) and deserialize it via `unsafeLookupStaticPtr` below it.

You can't define a `Binary` instance for `StaticPtr` (even if you wrap it in a newtype to avoid orphans) because the lookup cannot be done purely. But you can still define and use the serializer and deserializer as regular, nonoverloaded functions.

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me why `unsafeLookupStaticPtr` lives in `IO`. It seems that this sort of thing would probably play well with `TypeRep` serialization or similar.

Comment: I am not sure but I believe the reason was some backward compatibility issues in GHC 7.10. The Typeable API was changed in the later versions. As mentioned in this blog post: https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-23-static-pointers.html
""
The reason only the unsafe variant will ship in GHC 7.10 is because the safe variant will require a change to the Data.Typeable API to be truly safe, and because we do not yet store Typeable constraints in the internal compiler-generated table mentioned above.
""

The proposed function `lookupStaticPtr` never made it.